# Queria melhorar o desempenho do meu programa

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pyqt-4

Boa Tarde,

Atualmente estou criando uma interface, para uma aplicação, porém estou com um problema, com a função que criei.

```
def contornos(self):

    self.im = cv2.imread(self.imagem)
    im_copia = self.im.copy()

    imagem_cinza = cv2.cvtColor(im_copia, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Transforma a imagem em tons de cinza
    _,thresh = cv2.threshold(imagem_cinza,self.minThresh,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV) # Limiarização

    res = cv2.bitwise_and(im_copia,im_copia,mask = thresh)
    res_cinza = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _,thresht = cv2.threshold(res_cinza,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)


    _, self.contorno, _= cv2.findContours(thresht, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
    cv2.drawContours(im_copia,self.contorno,-1,(255,255,255),3)
    (self.contorno, _) = contours.sort_contours(self.contorno)    

    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im_copia, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.show()
```

Quando aciono essa pelo programa principal, a interface fica travada e pouco responsivo.

```
self.threshold_slice.valueChanged.connect(self.segmenta_foto)
```

esse é o método que a widget ativa:

```
def segmenta_foto(self):
    if self.diretorio_imagem.text() == '':
        self.msg = QtGui.QMessageBox()
        self.msg.setIcon(QtGui.QMessageBox.Critical)

        self.msg.setText("Erro: Não há imagem selecionada")
        self.msg.setInformativeText("Favor inserir uma imagem apertando o botão de OK")
        self.msg.setWindowTitle("Erro - 01")
        retval = self.msg.exec_()
    else:
        valor = self.threshold_slice.value()
        self.threshold_indicador.setText(str(valor))
        imagem = Tratamento_imagem(self.diretorio_imagem.text(),int(valor))
        imagem.contornos()
```

Há alguma forma de melhorar esse código, para que ele fique mais rápido? desculpem qualquer termo errado, programo em python a pouco tempo.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal aí é colocar a função que leva tempo para calcular (mesmo que "tempo" seja 0.2s - é o suficiente para a interface parecer não responsiva) numa thread separada.

Desta forma, enquanto que na thread principal, o Qt "faz as coisas dele", respondendo a eventos do usuário, etc..., em outra thread, os cálculos são feitos em fundo.

Você talvez tenha ouvido falar que "programação multi-threading é complicada". Bom, pdoe ser sim, bastante complicada, mas principalmente se você tem (1)  Threads que mexem em paralelo nas mesmas estruturas de dados (mesmo que estejam no disco); (2) implementar toda a lógicade comunicação entre as threads. - para (2), o Python já alivia bastante, fazendo com que variáveis globais, listas e dicionários sejam "thread safe" - e o Qt alivia mais ainda. Na verdade, o Qt acaba de implementar toda a lógica de comunicação que vocẽ precisaria. E (1) sua função vai realizar operações na imagem de forma independente do PyQT em si, e só vai precisar atualizar o resultado final.

Por fim - Python tem os mecanismos de thread dele mesmo, no módulo threading - mas se você usar essas, elas irão conflitar com o loop principal do Qt. Por isso, se sua aplicação é em Qt, você deve usar as "QThreads"

Acredito que esse tutorial seja detalhado o suficiente para você resolver
o seu problema aí - (alias, ele deve ser simples, já que você já tem pronto e isolado o código que vai rodar na thread):

https://nikolak.com/pyqt-threading-tutorial/